# Parent page for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types

Alright, there's been numerous topics about this, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I have one normal page, called "Resources".
Then I have several Custom Post Types. One of which is "Video's".

I want "Video's" to be a child page of "Resources". At the moment, I can both access the video's page by the URL: http://example.com/resources/videos AND http://example.com/videos (they both work).

My Videos CPT is as follows:

```php
function register_custom_post_video() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Videos', 'videos'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Video', 'video'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New Video', 'Video'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Video'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Video'),
        'new_item' => __('New Video'),
        'view_item' => __('View Video'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Videos'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Videos found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Videos found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources', 'with_front' => true),
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','author','excerpt','page-attributes')
    );
    
    register_post_type( 'videos' , $args );
    }
    add_action('init', 'register_custom_post_video');
```

But the rewrite doesn't seem to work. Also, when I resave the permalinks settings, it doesn't work.

I use `archive-videos.php` as the page.

Also, according to a WP Tuts+ quicktip, the

> Therefore, to make a hierarchical custom post type, you have to have the ‘page-attributes‘ set in the ‘supports‘ array and the ‘hierarchical‘ flag set to true. I hope this was helpful to you as well!

does not work either.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add page-attributes to the supports array e.g.

```
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes'),
```

This then should give you the parent functionality

Comment: I updated my answer to what I have now, where can I set the parent page? I realy don't get it :p

Comment: Adding `page-attributes` displays only posts from the current CPT

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to keep a Page that *looks* like a parent, but technically isn't.

When you register the CPT, you can make it look like the individual CPT posts are "children" of a Page by updating your `rewrite` argument:

```
'rewrite'     => array( 'slug' => 'resources/videos' ),
```

"Rewrite" tells WordPress where to keep the URLs. This will ensure your Videos archive ends up at http://example.com/resources/videos/ and individual videos end up at http://example.com/resources/videos/slug-of-a-single-video/.

Since the rewrite is now set "under" resources, you'll still be able to edit the Resources Page as a normal Page, and Videos will be a CPT Archive that appears to be a "child" of Resources.